# Passing data between two ActionResults in the same controller rendering different views in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have to pass th iddemande from one ActionResult to another in the same controller but it failed with TempData or Session because each ActionResult render a different view.
So I need your help to know how to pass data between those two controllers from "Details" to "Sortie".

**my controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? num,int iddemande)
        {
            TempData["num"] = num;
            //Session["iddemande"] = iddemande;
            TempData["iddemande"] = iddemande;
            if (num == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var listdemandes = (from d in db.Demande_Gabarit
                                join g in db.Gabarits
                                    on d.idPoste equals g.idPoste into ThisList
                                from g in ThisList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                select new
                                {
                                    NumDemande = d.NumDemande,
                                    Emetteur = d.Emetteur,
                                    Date = d.Date,
                                    Quantite = d.Quantite,
                                    Designation = g.DesignationGabarit,
                                    Produit=d.Postes.Produits.Reference,
                                    Ligne = d.Ligne.designation
                                }).ToList().Select(x => new DemandeViewModel()
                                {
                                    NumDemande = x.NumDemande,
                                    Emetteur = x.Emetteur,
                                    Date = x.Date,
                                    Quantite = x.Quantite,
                                    DesignationGabarit = x.Designation,
                                    designation = x.Ligne,
                                    Reference= (int)x.Produit
                                }).Where(x => x.NumDemande == num);


            return View(listdemandes.DistinctBy(x=>x.DesignationGabarit));

        }
//Get Sortie
        public ActionResult Sortie(Int64 id)
        {
             TempData["codebarre"] = id;

            return View();

        }
        //Post Sortie
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Sortie(DemandeViewModel postData)
        {
            Int64 cb = postData.CodeBarre;

            var mvtrepository = new MvtRepository(db);
            var gabaritrepository = new GabaritRepository(db);





            if (Convert.ToInt64(TempData["codebarre"]) == cb)
            {
                var mvtInsert = mvtrepository.InsertMvt(DateTime.Now, Convert.ToInt64(TempData["codebarre"]), 2);
                var idDemande = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["iddemande"]);
                Demande_Gabarit demande =
                    demanderepository.Get(x => x.id_demande == idDemande).SingleOrDefault();

                demande.QtLivree = 1;
                demanderepository.Update(demande);

                return RedirectToAction("Details");
            }


            else
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

        }
```

Comment: Where is it not working(which specific method/line)? What is your expected behavior  ? Session should work.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply..and what's not working for me is that iddemande is null in the  ActionResult"Sortie"

Comment: @Shyju I edited my question..I meant between two actionResults in the same controller

Comment: You mean, between your GET and POST action methods ? Why do you think it is not working ? Is `TempData["codebarre"]` null in your HttpPost action method ?

Comment: @oumaima is session not working? did you try to use session instead of TempData?

Comment: @Shyju from my GET to POST it works .. but the problem is between the ActionResult "Details" and my ActionResult "Sortie"

Comment: In your question, there is no code which you reads the data you set to Session in the Details action method. Then why do expect that to work. Write to code to read it as needed and use it

Comment: @Shyju the problem is in TempData["iddemande"]

Comment: I tried with TempData and Session but it doesn't work

Comment: if you use this Session ["iddemande"] then what value are you getting in Sortie ?

Comment: @Usman i get "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TempData value is available only to the next request. that means if you set some value to your Details action and you are navigating to the Sortie GET action next, You will be able to retrieve it. But then if you are submitting the form and hitting the Sortie HTTPPost action, It will not be available.

One option is to set the tempdata value again so that it will be accessible in the very next request as well.

```
public ActionResult Sortie(Int64 id)
{       
    TempData["codebarre"] = id; 
    var t = TempData["iddemande"];
    TempData["iddemande"] = t;
    return View();
}
```

Another option (better/clean option IMHO) is to pass this value through your form. So instead of setting again to the TempData in the GET action, You keep this TempData value inside a form element and when the form is submitted, this value will be sent to your HttpPost action method. You can add a parameter to your action method to read this.

So in your Sortie view form,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" value="@TempData["iddemande"]" name="iddemande" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
```

And in your http post action

```
[HttpPost]        
public ActionResult Sortie(DemandeViewModel postData,int iddemande)
{
   // You can use the value of iddemande
   // to do  : Return something
}
```

Regarding Session, It should work as long as you are correctly reading it. Session value will be available for all the requests after it is set, until the session ends.

Comment: Thanks  a lot and it works for me by using Session correctly ..Thank you..you saved "my Code"  ^^